# ajaxFileUpload in a gridview not calling VB.NET Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Okay I have a vb gridview that looks like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvMain" Width="100%"  runat="server">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEdit" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Size="15px">
     <asp:AjaxFileUpload OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUploadEvent" ID="AjaxFileUpload11" runat="server" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1"  />
       </asp:Panel>
      <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" ID="lbtnIcon" runat="server">View</asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle />
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The rest of the page is irrelevant but I do have all the code that makes the ajaxFileUpload work. The problem I am having is when the fileupload is in the gridview it won't call the event that it calls while it is outside the gridview.

Here is the code I have for my Gridview.

```
Public Sub grvMain_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grvMain.RowCommand
    Dim intIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim pnlEdit As Panel = grvMain.Rows(intIndex).FindControl("pnlEdit")
pnlEdit.visible = true
End Sub
```

So when the linkbutton is pressed in the gridview it enabled the panel that contains the file upload.

Code for the OnUploadComplete event is :

```
Sub AjaxFileUploadEvent(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName)
    Dim strUploadPath As String = "~/images/"
    AjaxFileUpload11.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strUploadPath) + filename)
End Sub
```

All the code is doing is saving the file in a folder. Also I have tried changing the ajaxfileupload to `OnClientUploadComplete="AjaxFileUploadEvent"` and it still does not call the event. I just need to know how to make it call the correct event instead of just doing a postback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your web config do you have something like the following below..

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: yes I do have that in my web config file. I also have  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %> and I have a script manager on the page

Comment: what happens if you move / wrap the control inside of an UpDatePanel...? I am trying the same thing in C# equivalent and I have zero issues..

Comment: when I put the ajaxfileupload inside the update panel it gives me the error that Type 'System.web.ui.updatepanel' does not have a public property named 'ajaxfileupload'

Comment: because the name of your control `ID` is `AjaxFileUpload11` it's case sensitive you know

Comment: vb is not case sensitive. and where am i using the ID in the wrong case

Comment: here is a link that you can try as well as slightly refactor you code that when copied and pasted works - http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/06/ajax-fileupload-control-in-aspnet-or.html